# Block user in asmack android

Tags: android, asmack

I am not able to block user and below is the code i am using

```
List<PrivacyItem> privacyItems = new Vector<PrivacyItem>();
                    PrivacyItem item = new PrivacyItem(PrivacyItem.Type.jid.toString(), false, 2);

                item.setFilterIQ(true);
                item.setFilterMessage(true);
                item.setFilterPresence_in(true);
                item.setFilterPresence_out(true);

                item.setValue(friendName);
                item.setOrder(23);

                privacyItems.add(item);
                PrivacyListManager privacyManager = PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                String privacyListName = MailManager.getAddress();
                try {
                    //privacyManager.updatePrivacyList(friendName, privacyItems);
                    privacyManager.createPrivacyList(friendName, privacyItems);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                }
```

Comment: i am not getting any error , users are added in privacy list but incoming messages and out going messages are not blocked.

Comment: check whether you are doing all the things properly mentioned here in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610788/issue-in-blocking-user-in-chatlist-using-smack-and-open-fire-server